# Command is not triggered when called from CollectionView's ItemTemplate using Binding

Tags: xamarin.forms, mvvm, data-binding, navigation

I have trouble navigating from the ViewModel using binding, the command async method OnMovieClicked doesn't fire at all.

```
public class MainViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        private List<Movie> popularMovies;
        public List<Movie> PopularMovies
        {
            get => popularMovies;
            set => SetProperty(ref popularMovies, value);
        }

        public ICommand NavigateToMovieCommand { get; set; }

        private readonly TMDBService tmdbService;
        private readonly INavigationService navigationService;

        public MainViewModel()
        {
            tmdbService = new TMDBService();
            navigationService = new NavigationService();

            NavigateToMovieCommand = new Command<int>(async (id) => await OnMovieClicked(id));

            InitAsync();
        }

        private async void InitAsync()
        {
            PopularMovies = await tmdbService.GetPopularMovies();
        }

        private async Task OnMovieClicked(int id)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("****Navigate");
            var viewModel = new MovieViewModel(id);
            await navigationService.PushAsync(new MoviePage(viewModel));
        }
```

it doesn't write anything to the console, and i've already tested my navigation service and it's working fine

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:viewmodels="clr-namespace:MovieApp.ViewModels"
             Title="New Releases"
             x:Class="MovieApp.MainPage"
             x:Name="MoviePage"
             BackgroundColor="DarkSlateGray">

    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <viewmodels:MainViewModel/>
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>

    <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding PopularMovies}"
                    SelectionMode="None"
                    ItemSizingStrategy="MeasureAllItems"
                    ItemsLayout="VerticalGrid, 3">
        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ContentView>
                    <Frame HasShadow="True"
                           Margin="10"
                           WidthRequest="80"
                           BackgroundColor="LightSlateGray"
                           Padding="0"
                           CornerRadius="15">

                        <Grid RowDefinitions="120,25">

                            <Image Aspect="AspectFill"
                                    Source="{Binding PosterPath}"
                                    Grid.RowSpan="2"/>

                            <BoxView WidthRequest="80"
                                   Grid.Row="1"
                                   Opacity="0.85"
                                   BackgroundColor="LightSlateGray"/>

                            <Label Grid.Row="1"
                                    TextColor="White"
                                    HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                                    Padding="8,0"
                                    Text="{Binding Title}"
                                    LineBreakMode="TailTruncation"/>

                           <Button Grid.RowSpan="2"
                                   BackgroundColor="Blue"
                                   Command="{Binding BindingContext.NavigateToMovieCommand, Source={x:Reference MoviePage}}"
                                   CommandParameter="{Binding Id}"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </Frame>
                </ContentView>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    </CollectionView>
</ContentPage>
```

I've already added both x:Name and x:Reference properties to the Page and Command

i don't think i'm doing anything wrong in the XAML file, but it's gotta be a binding issue since it doesn't print the log line to the console.

**UPDATE:**

here's the Movie model

```
    public partial class Movie
    { 
        [JsonProperty("id")]
        public long Id { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("poster_path")]
        public string PosterPath {
            get;
            set;
        }

        [JsonProperty("release_date")]
        public string ReleaseDate { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("title")]
        public string Title { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("vote_average")]
        public double VoteAverage { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("credits", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public Credits Credits { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Take a look at the Bind to Ancestor info for relative binding: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/relative-bindings#bind-to-an-ancestor

Comment: @Depechie i refactored to use ancestor, but the behavior remains the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You code is ok, having no problem, but you don't post some code about `Movie`, the `Id property` type is `int` or `string`, if the `Movie` class `Id property` is `string`, passing `Id` prarmeter as `int` type in `NavigateToMovieCommand`, the command will not fire.

```
 NavigateToMovieCommand = new Command<int>(async (id) => await OnMovieClicked(id));
```

I use the following `Movie` class, setting `Id` property type as `int`, and use your code to test, Buttom command can be fired, having no problem.

```
public class Movie
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string PosterPath { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I updated the question to include the model for the Movie, the id is of type long, i switched it to long in the command method, but it didn't do anything.

Comment: Nvm, i forgot to update Command<int> to Command<long>, it worked, thanks a lot.